# How to access this variable

Tags: php, arrays

Hi Guys :) I have something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus Object
        (
            [remoteUpload:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUpload Object
                (
                    [id:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUpload:private] => xxxx
                    [folderId:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUpload:private] => xxxx
                )

            [remoteUrl:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => https://openload.co/embed/xxxxx
            [status:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => finished
            [bytesLoaded:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => 
            [bytesTotal:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => 
            [addedDate:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-07-21 10:53:55.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [lastUpdateDate:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-07-21 10:53:55.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                )

            [fileId:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => xxxx
            [url:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private] => https://openload.co/f/xxxx <------------ Here is what I want to write to a variable
        )

)
```

(At the end of the code is a comment)
How to do that ?

I tried something like that: print_r($myarray[0][url:Ideneal\OpenLoad\Entity\RemoteUploadStatus:private])
and nothing.

Comment: That's a private property. Have you tried to check if this class has a method that returns that property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `RemoteUploadStatus` object methods:

```
$myarray[0]->getUrl();
```

Ref.: https://github.com/Ideneal/OpenLoad/blob/master/src/Entity/RemoteUploadStatus.php